# Java Error: could not find or load main class Vehicle

Tags: java

I am trying to load Vehicle class after I compiled it successfully but this error occures:
`Error: could not find or load main class Vehicle`

I think that there may be a mistake in my code, which is the following:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    String make;
    String color;
    boolean engineState;

    void startEngine()
    {
       if (engineState == true)
          System.out.println("The engine is already on!");
       else
       {
           engineState = true;
           System.out.println("The engine is now on.");
       }
    }

    void showAttributes()
    {
      System.out.println("This vehicle is a " + color + "
      " + make);
      if (engineState == true)
        System.out.println("The engine is on.");
      else
        System.out.println("The engine is off.");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Create a new vehicle and set its attributes.
        Vehicle car = new Vehicle();
        car.make = "Rolls Royce";
        car.color = "Midnight blue";
        System.out.println("Calling showAttributes ...");
        car.showAttributes();

        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println("Starting the engine ...");
        car.startEngine();
        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println("Calling showAttributes ...");
        car.showAttributes();

        // Let’s try to start the engine again.
        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println("Starting the engine ...");
        car.startEngine();

    }
}
```

Comment: The mistake is not in your code, but in the command you use to start it.

Comment: I mean you posted all the irrelevant information and none of the relevant. You can't be helped with the question as it currently stands.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your code, but rather in how you are launching it.

Find where your class files are compiled to, and add this root to your classpath.

For example, if your class files are compiled to:

```
<project root>/classes
```

Then you can run them as follows:

```
java -cp <project root>/classes Vehicle
```

Take a look at the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) on the subject for more details

Comment: i am using me command prompt to test it. is there somewhere else i could run it? i will also check location you said

Comment: I tried your solution but the same error occures. If the javac Vehicle.java has worked a file named Vehicle.class should have been created right?? it seems that no such file has been created

Comment: If the javac Vehicle.java reported success, then a class file will have been generated - we just need to find out where :-) Are you building this via an IDE, or from the command prompt?  If from the prompt you can try this: javac -d . Vehicle.java - this should generate the class file in the same directory that you're in - can you try this and let me know if it works?

Comment: ok i typed this. let me tell you that the javac Vehicle.java does not report anything. it just runs and the command prompt shows again tha c:\labs\CourseTwo directory.Should it say something? i created another .java before and it worked just fine after i fixed the path directory.

Comment: so it seems that the class is not created at all, that's why i said that there might be an issue with my code. :(

Comment: If your are in c:\labs\CourseTwo, and if Vehicle.java is also in c:\labs\CourseTwo, then if you type javac -d . Vehicle.java then you should have c:\labs\CourseTwo\Vehicle.class.  javac wont output anything if you're succesful, so what you're seeing should be ok.

Comment: I've just tried your code above, and it compiles file - there is a valid class file generated which can then be run. Your code is fine :-)

Comment: i did all the above and there is no file compiled in my CousreTwo folder or anywhere else. it just doesn't compile anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my eclipse works fine, this is the result:

```
Calling showAttributes ...
This vehicle is a Midnight blueRolls Royce
The engine is off.
--------
Starting the engine ...
The engine is now on.
--------
Calling showAttributes ...
This vehicle is a Midnight blueRolls Royce
The engine is on.
--------
Starting the engine ...
The engine is already on!
```

The code works

Comment: The Vehicle.class is not created when i do the following: javac Vehicle.java